# Facebook Application Parse Error CSS

Tags: facebook

Im getting some parse erros when loading in my facebook app through the canvas. Its in an iframe. Can anyone tell me where I can start to look for documentation regarding this?

```
Errors whilst loading page from application

Parse errors:

CSS Error (line 40 char 36): Error in parsing value for property.: 'font'  Declaration dropped.

CSS Error (line 183 char 18): Expected declaration.  Skipped to next declaration.
CSS Error (line 272 char 65): Unknown property.: '-webkit-border-radius'  Declaration dropped.
CSS Error (line 272 char 110): Unknown property.: 'border-radius'  Declaration dropped.
CSS Error (line 272 char 135): Unknown property.: '-webkit-box-shadow'  Declaration dropped.
CSS Error (line 272 char 181): Unknown property.: '-moz-box-shadow'  Declaration dropped.
CSS Error (line 272 char 221): Unknown property.: 'box-shadow'  Declaration dropped.
CSS Error (line 317 char 23): Unknown property.: '-webkit-border-radius'  Declaration dropped.
CSS Error (line 319 char 15): Unknown property.: 'border-radius'  Declaration dropped.
```

Thanks

--Mark

Comment: please dont give me the facebook developer home page. I just dont know what to search for on there. Everything else is coming up blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about that unless your *layout* if fine, facebook imposes a host of restrictions. Note that as developer only *you* will see those messages and not the users of the application

Answer (score 1):

yes sarfraz is absolutely right. This is only the developer error so d'nt worry about those.